# RecyclerView with fade effect

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fade

I'm trying to implement a RecyclerView with fade edges.
I'm using these attributes:

```
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:fadingEdgeLength="800dp"
android:fillViewport="false"
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical|horizontal"
```

And getting this result:

[image]

The problem is that the bottom items (from Green to the bottom) are faded and never get un-faded.

Is there a way to tell the RecyclerView to scroll until the last item is above the "Bla Bla" frame? but still have the edge effect.

Thanks :-)